# How to get started with Eclipse (Version 4.0) and JBoss (Version 7)?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jboss

I want to run a   HelloWorld servlet in JBoss via Eclipse. I have searched a lot, but I am not able to configure Eclipse and JBoss. I have mentioned the versions above. Could you please guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/luna/) on Eclipse Luna. Either download it on Eclipse Marketplace or install it.